# Show counter / index in SAPUI5 List Control through XML view

Tags: xml, sapui5

Is there a way to access an internal counter or index property of list items in an XML view, while iterating over the items of a SAPUI5 List control? The use case could be to simply enumerate the items. Or in my case it would be to give a special treatment to the very first list item.

What I am looking for is something like the hypothetical `$counter` in the following example:

```
  <List items="{MyModel>/MyRootElement}">
    <items>
      <CustomListItem>
        <Text text="This is element number {MyModel>$counter}." />
      </CustomListItem>
    </items>
  </List>
```

I know I can solve this using JS in the controller. But I would be interested in a pure XML solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, there is no built-in "pseudo-property" that would contain the index of the element. If we especially think about sorting, then I would imagine that there would be developers wanting the numbering to reflect the sorting and other developers wanting it to be stable with regards to sorting.

Nevertheless, in some concrete cases, it is possible to actually number your rows using a pure XML solution.

If the `MyRootElement` is an array, you could always do something like ([working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g93owbrt/4/)):

```xml
<List items="{/MyRootElement}">
    <StandardListItem title="{name}" 
        counter="{= ${/MyRootElement}.indexOf(${}) + 1 }" />
</List>
```

If it is an object (i.e. a map-like structure) then you will need to use the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) function. It provides the correct numbering because it is guaranteed to give the values in the same order as a for .. in loop which is actually used by the Model to create the bindings and ultimately the list items. It should be noted that the `Object.values()` function is not supported in IE and might require a polyfill. Example (and [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u330e4m/4/)):

```xml
<List items="{/MyRootElement}">
    <StandardListItem title="{name}" 
        counter="{= Object.values(${/MyRootElement}).indexOf(${}) + 1 }" />
</List>
```

---

### Later edit: Binding path explanation

In the code samples, I have used the `${}` construct to access the current, unnamed model's binding context's data object.

The rules related to building the binding paths are the following ([as specified in the documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/2888af49635949eca14fa326d04833b9)):

- The model name followed by a `>` sign. If this part is skipped, then the unnamed (default) model is used. The rest of the path after the `>` sign is used to find the referenced data inside the model.
- If the path starts with a `/`, then it is an absolute path (the referenced data lookup is performed from the root object of the model). Otherwise, it is a relative path.
- Relative paths are concatenated with the binding path of the nearest ancestor control which has a binding context for the model. If the resulting path is still relative, this is repeated recursively until an absolute one is obtained.
- For JSON models, the path is split by the `/` sign and then the JSON object tree is traversed using the attribute names obtained from this split.

Concretely, in the case of `${}`, the binding path itself is '' (an empty string). Using the rules above, this would be a relative path for the unnamed (default) model. As the path is empty, no attribute traversal is done (because there are no path components obtained after the path split).

Similarly, for named models, the `${MyModelName>}` expression binding would have the same effect.

Comment: This is ingenious! I was not aware of the fact that `{}` (empty curly brackets) is the notation to access the complete current item of an unnamed model in a loop. Thinking about it this is perfectly logical, as this is what remains, if you remove the object name from the notation that returns objects within loops (like {name} in your example). You might want to include that detail into your answer:  `{}` = current item in a loop for unnamed models, `{ModelName>}` = current item in a loop for named models. Together with indexOf() this perfectly solves my problem. THX!

Comment: I have updated the answer to also include the binding path reasoning.

Comment: I tried:
<Label text="{= ${MyModelName>/}.indexOf(${}) + 1 }"/>
But i get a 0 for every row.

Comment: Is the root of your model an array? I.e., does ${MyModelName>/} resolve to an array?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any counter in the table, however a workaround could be using a factory function and getting the row number fromt he row id:

Here the [DEMO](https://jsbin.com/gihebonusa/edit?html,output) using Northwind and here the snippet:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
   src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="my.own.controller">
   <Page>
     <Table items="{path:'/Orders', factory: '.createRow'}">
          <columns>
              <Column>
                  <Text text="#"/>
              </Column>
              <Column>
                  <Text text="Order ID"/>
              </Column>
          </columns>
        </Table>
   </Page>
  </mvc:View> 
    </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
     createRow: function (sId, oContext) {
       console.log(sId);
       console.log(oContext);
       
       var rowNumber = sId.split("-")[sId.split("-").length-1];
       
       var oRow = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
              new sap.m.Text({
                text: rowNumber
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text: {path: "OrderID"}
              })
            ]
          })
          
          return oRow;
       }
   });
   
   
 
   /*** THIS IS THE "APPLICATION" CODE ***/
   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   // Using here the HEROKU Proxy to avoid a CORS issue
   var uri = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc"; // local proxy for cross-domain access
   var oNorthwindModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, {
    maxDataServiceVersion: "2.0"
   }); 
   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above
   // Set the OData Model
   myView.setModel(oNorthwindModel);
   
   
   myView.placeAt('content');
  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```